# AngularJs call a function only after a factory function is called

Tags: angularjs, factory

I am trying login user using factory function in angularjs.
This is my code for checking login info:

```
$scope.login = function(user) {
    if(!$rootScope.isLoggedIn) {
        LoginService.login($scope.user, $scope);
        console.log($rootScope.isLoggedIn);  
    } else { 
        $location.path('/home');
    }          
}
```

While `LoginService` factory service look like this:

```
.factory('LoginService', ['$http', '$location', '$rootScope', function($http,$location, $rootScope) {
    return {
        login: function(user, scope) {
            $rootScope.processGoingOn = true;
            var $promise = $http.post('user.php', user);   
            $promise.then(function(msg) {
                var responseData = msg.data;
                console.log(responseData);
                if(responseData['login_success'] == 'true') { 
                    $rootScope.isLoggedIn = true;                    
                    $rootScope.processGoingOn = false; 
                    // success redirect
                } else {
                    $rootScope.isLoggedIn = false;
                    $rootScope.processGoingOn = false; 
                    // try login again 
                }        
            });
        }
        ....
    }
});
```

The change in `$rootScope.isLoggedIn` is not reflecting back to `$scope.login()` function in either success or failure, any suggestions?

Comment: Your `factory`looks like it should be a `service`

Answer (score 0):

this is because login function is returned before promise is resolved.

on way to do this can be return $promise like this

```
login: function(user, scope){
    $rootScope.processGoingOn = true;
    return $http.post('user.php', user);   
}
```

call then where you have `console.log($rootScope.isLoggedIn);`